# Model.Records returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The problem that I am facing is that in my foreach it is being returned as null, because of my delete method in my controller. I have tried setting a get set value for the viewModel, but it is still returning null. In my Index however it does return values so as long as my Delete Action method isn't included it works. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public class LansingMileageController : Controller
        {

            private TravelSOCCEntities2 db = new TravelSOCCEntities2();

            public LansingMileageViewModel vm{ get; set; }
            //GET: LansingMileage
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                LansingMileageViewModel viewModel = new LansingMileageViewModel();
                var results = SELECT * FROM LansingMileage
                LansingMileageViewModel viewModel = new LansingMileageViewModel();
                viewModel.Records = results.ToList();
                return View(viewModel);
            }

            [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
            [OnAction(ButtonName = "Create")]
            public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "ExpMonthYr,TripType,TravelDate")] LansingMileage lansing)
            {

                string expenseDate = Request.Form["expenseDate"];
                string travelDate = Request.Form["travelDate"];
                string triptype = Request.Form["triptype"];

                lansing.ExpMonthYr = Convert.ToDateTime(expenseDate);
                lansing.TravelDate = Convert.ToDateTime(travelDate);
                lansing.TripType = Convert.ToInt32(triptype);

                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        db.LansingMileages.Add(lansing);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }
                // will catch any error thrown and store it to a text file
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            //GET:
            public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }

                var lansing = db.LansingMileages.Find(id);


                if (lansing == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View("Index", vm);
            }

            //POST:
            [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
            [OnAction(ButtonName = "Delete")]
            //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Delete(int id)
            {
                LansingMileage lansing = db.LansingMileages.Find(id);
                db.LansingMileages.Remove(lansing);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my ViewModel

```
public class LansingMileageViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Models.LansingMileage> Records { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpMonthYr { get; set; }
        public DateTime TravelDate { get; set; }
        public LansingMileage SelectedLansingMileage { get; set; }
        public string DisplayMode { get; set; }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model TravelSOCC.ViewModels.LansingMileageViewModel
 <table id="LansingData" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Row ID</th>
                <th>Expense Month/Yr</th>
                <th>Travel Date</th>
                <th>Travel Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Records)
            {                
            <tr id="@item.RowIndex">

                @*<td><input type="submit" formaction="/LansingMileage/DeleteEntry/@item.RowIndex" value="Delete" name="Deletebtn" id="delete" /></td>*@
                @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RowIndex }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');", @class = "delete-button" })</td>
                <td>@item.RowIndex</td>
                <td>@item.ExpMonthYr</td>
                <td>@item.TravelDate</td>
                <td>@item.TripType</td>

            </tr>
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: `return View("Index", lansing);` Is that the correct view to display for the "Delete" (GET) action? That view model certainly isn't the right type for it.

Comment: The hidden gem is in your `**db query**` on `results.ToList()`. To me it looks like EF core returns entities with lazy proxies. Can you show the `**db query**`.

Comment: That explains the type name with two GUIDs' worth of hex in the name (you're right about the proxy class). The problem is in the `lansing` parameter. It's a list of entities, not a `LansingMileageViewModel` with a list of entities in the `Records` property.

Comment: What's the return type for var in: var results = **db query**

Comment: @madreflection no lansing isn't the right call it should be viewmodel which ties to my LansingMileageViewModel, but every time I call viewmodel it forces my foreach to be null.

Comment: @FrankNielsen I added the db query as you requested. Please let me know what other information is needed. Thank you!

Comment: Refocus your question on why `Model.Records` is `null` when you pass a `LansingMileageViewModel`. Otherwise, it's an XY problem.

Comment: Do you have `UseLazyLoadingProxies` in your `Startup.cs`? If so, disable/remove it.

Comment: @madreflection I refocused it to the Model.records

Comment: @FrankNielsen not that I know of but where would I check?

Comment: `UseLazyLoadingProxies` could also be placed in you `***dbcontext.cs` on the `OnConfiguring` method. Just do a simple text search on it. EF do not have lazy loading on by default.

Comment: They are set to false

Comment: So it is a .Net Framework, not .Net core project ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199204/discussion-between-dominik-willaford-and-frank-nielsen).